# How to start celery in background of terminal in Django

Tags: django, django-celery

I ma starting celery  as

```
python manage.py celeryd
```

It is working but in foreground . Then to test commands i need to start another terminal and do stuff there.

is there any way to start that in background. I tried this

```
python manage.py celeryd &
```

But then again it comes at foreground

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're looking for `celeryd_detach`, available since at least 2.4

```
python manage.py celeryd_detach
```

Comment: It worked but is it same as running celeryd . for what purpose celerybeat is used. from now should i use celeryd or celeryd_detach. i thinking of running that on startup

Comment: `celeryd` is better for development as you can see its output.  I run celeryd in a tab within my terminal app, while my editor is in another tab.  As for `celerybeat`, I'd take a look at the docs. http://ask.github.com/celery/reference/celery.bin.celerybeat.html

Comment: How do you cleanly restart `celery` with this approach once you change your code?

Answer (score 4):

You can use this to get celeryd to work in the background

```
$ nohup celeryd start &
```

The above command pushes the celery daemon to the background.

Answer (score 4):

You can try "Supervisor". Install "django-supervisor" in your project, create a supervisor.conf in the same folder than your manage.py.

then, you just run:

```
python manager.py supervisor --daemonize
```

My supervisor.conf:

```
[program:celeryd]
command={{ PYTHON }} {{ PROJECT_DIR }}/manage.py celeryd -l info
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopwaitsecs = 600

[program:autoreload]
exclude=true
[program:runserver]
exclude=true
[program:celerybeat]
exclude=true
```