# manage.py celeryd -B. How to run it in background?

Tags: python, django, django-celery

I use django celery

```
python manage.py celeryd -B

[2013-05-01 23:42:58,583: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@aaa ready.
```

How to run it in background?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665893/how-to-start-celery-in-background-of-terminal-in-django.

Comment: I use [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) for development and [init.d scripts](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/extra/generic-init.d/celeryd) for production.

Comment: You can use supervisorctl to execute it in background. You have here a simple tutorial: http://thomassileo.com/blog/2012/08/20/how-to-keep-celery-running-with-supervisor/

Answer (score 1):

python manage.py celeryd -B --detach

You can refer to: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.celeryev.html?highlight=detach#cmdoption-celery-events--detach